# how can i unserialize a field whic is in the serializable class

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2008, serialization

I want to make a class serializable but i dont want make serializable some fileds in this class. how can do that?

Thanks for your helps.

Comment: There are different serialization mechanisms : XML, JSON, binary, ... and different libraries that can handle them. You might need to be a little more specific.

Comment: if you are talking XML look up XmlIgnore

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using [BinaryFormatter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.formatters.binary.binaryformatter.aspx) to perform the serialization you might add the [`[NonSerialized]`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.nonserializedattribute.aspx) attribute to the **field** you wish to exclude.

For [XmlSerializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlserializer.aspx) look at the [`[XmlIgnore]`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlignoreattribute.aspx) attribute.

For [DataContractSerializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.datacontractserializer.aspx) look at the [`[IgnoreDataMember]`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.ignoredatamemberattribute.aspx) attribute.